# Sort a txt file based on numbers

Tags: python, txt

I have a txt file of data that looks like this:

```
@0 #1
@30 #2
@750 #2
@20 #3
@500 #3
@2500 #4
@460 #4
@800 #1
@2200 #1
@290 #2
@4700 #4
@570 #1
```

How do I sort the file based on the integer between the @ and #?

The output should be:

```
@0 #1
@20 #3
@30 #2
@290 #2
@460 #4
@500 #3
@570 #1
@750 #2
@800 #1
@2200 #1
@2500 #4
@4700 #4
```

Comment: supposing you already have read the file and the values are in a list. Then you can sort the values like that: lines.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[1:-2])).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to read in the text and split it by new lines, then use the sorted function using only the integer part of line as the key.

```
with open('my_text_file.txt') as textfile:
    lines = textfile.read().split('\n')    # ['@0 #1', '@30 #2', '@750 #2', '@20 #3', '@500 #3', '@2500 #4', '@460 #4', '@800 #1', '@2200 #1', '@290 #2', '@4700 #4', '@570 #1']
    lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda i: int(i[1:i.index('#') -1]))  # ['@0 #1', '@20 #3', '@30 #2', '@290 #2', '@460 #4', '@500 #3', '@570 #1', '@750 #2', '@800 #1', '@2200 #1', '@2500 #4', '@4700 #4']
    txt = '\n'.join(lines)

with open('my_new_text_file.txt', 'wt') as textfile:
    textfile.write(txt)
```

output

```
@0 #1
@20 #3
@30 #2
@290 #2
@460 #4
@500 #3
@570 #1
@750 #2
@800 #1
@2200 #1
@2500 #4
@4700 #4
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done cleanly with a regular expression

```
import re

with open("somefile.txt") as file:
    lines = sorted((line.strip() for line in file), 
            key=lambda s: int(re.match(r"@(\d+)\s*#", s).group(1)))
print(lines)
```

This will raise an error if any strings don't match the pattern, which is the right thing to do if the file format is strict. You could instead write a function that checks the regex and returns a default value.